# How to get ios app I was working on from phone to computer?

Tags: ios, linux, xcode, command-line, terminal

I accidentally ran rm -rf on my terminal on my mac and lost everything, including an app project I was working on. Is it possible to somehow transfer the app project that I had deployed on my iPhone back to my computer in any way? Just so I can see what I can salvage?

Comment: Just restore from your backups or source code control. You do use both of those, right? If not, the best you can do is recover some resources in the app bundle.

Comment: I don't use either of those :( How do you recover things from the app bundle?

Comment: Use Xcode, go to the Devices window and download the app.

Comment: How do you download an app from this window?

Comment: Actually you don't. It's only the app's container. My mistake. You used to be able to access ipa files when you used iTunes to backup an iOS device. I'm not sure if that works any more.

Comment: So there is no way to get this app off my phone and onto my computer?

Comment: the app on the phone is from code that is compiled and linked so not sure what you are looking to get from that? do you not have your app development in a folder that is synched to your iCloud account? maybe you could restore from that.

Comment: You can't get the app source code back from the app that you ran on the phone.  If you did "rm -rf" and lost your Xcode project, you might be screwed. (sorry!)  Try going to the folder that it was in and do "ls -la" and see if you see a .git folder.  Otherwise try Time Machine.  Otherwise try iCloud (if you sync'd your Documents or Desktop folder and that's where the project was).

Answer (score 0):

You can't get the Xcode app project back from the app that was installed on your phone.

If you're using source control (such as with **git**), you may be able to go back to a prior version.  To check, go to the command-line and do

```
% git log
```

See if it shows any history.

Otherwise, if you stored your project in your *Documents* or *Desktop* folders and have those folders synchronized with iCloud, you **might** be able to get it back by going to *iCloud.com* and checking if you can download it. However, because these folders are synchronized, doing this right away is important, because it will synchronize the deletion.  This is why a cloud-sync'd folder isn't considered a backup.

If you have Time Machine configured on your Mac, you can check if there is a version available there.  Open Time Machine from Launchpad -> Other -> Time Machine, or click the Time Machine icon in the upper right corner of your Mac screen (looks like a clock with an arrow/circle around it), then click "Enter Time Machine".  If you're able to do this, you can go to the folder and browse previous versions by time.

Lastly, check any other backup solution you may have, such as Backblaze, for example.  Backblaze is a cloud backup solution.  It also has an icon up top on your Mac desktop -- it looks like a flame.

If none of these work, you're out of luck (**sorry!**).  Learn about git, and use Bitbucket or Github with it.  Set up time machine.  Also set up a cloud backup, like Backblaze.  I use all of those.  Hopefully one of these works for you!